# Should I use “cool” to talk about up-to-date data?

Tags: word-usage, terminology, french

I’m working on a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) project, so the *“fraicheur”* of data is quite important.

I know that the translation of *“frais”* is *“cool”*. Should I use this word in an IT technical environment (not only for REST project, this problematic also exists with sessions, caching, cookies, ...)?

Comment: Definitely don't use "cool". "Current", "recent", "up-to-date", "latest", "fresh", etc. could all work.

Comment: _Cool_ is not _the_ translation of _frais_. It is _a_ possible translation, and in this case, certainly not the most appropriate.

Comment: fraicheur = freshness

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to describe up-to-date (current) data, you will be best understood describing it as **“fresh”**.

I work in the (US) tech sphere and hear this phrasing frequently. And I'm not alone:

[image: Google Ngram comparison of “fresh data”, “topical data” and “cool data”]

[A quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=data+freshness) confirms that “data freshness” is a common and appropriate term, as here:

> However, problems lie in the **data freshness**[;] information in warehouse is not always **up-to-date.**
> <sub>Source: [Wikipedia - Data Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integration#History)</sub>

There's also this example [relaxing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/4796/relaxing) found on Stack Overflow:

> Is it possible to conditionally select the data source? Meaning presenting the data from the REST API or the local models depending on their **"freshness"**?
> <sub>Source: [Stack Overflow - Django calling REST API from models or views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479095/django-calling-rest-api-from-models-or-views)</sub>

And one last n-gram comparing “data freshness” and “data currency”, also from [relaxing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/4796/relaxing):

[image: Google Ngram comparison of “data freshness” and “data currency”]

Comment: I wonder (and this is for @FumbleFingers, too) if *current* or *most current* (data) might not be the least ambiguous adjective, and data *currency* the appropriate nominal. According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=data+freshness%2Cdata+currency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdata%20freshness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdata%20currency%3B%2Cc0) *data currency* is three times as frequent as *data freshness*.

Comment: @StoneyB: I worked for decades on data analysis for bus companies. Maybe they all tended to adopt the terminology of a small number of "atypical" technical staff, but to the best of my recollection *everyone* to whom the distinction made any difference referred to *historical* and *topical* data. The latter, being primarily relevant to ongoing operational concerns, usually meant only days (or at most a few weeks) old, for answering questions like *"Did the driver hand in the right amount of cash to match ticket sales in yesterday's shift?"*. The former would analyse trends, perhaps over years.

Comment: (judging by the downvotes, not only OP's co-workers, but ELL users in general, are unfamiliar with this usage! :)

Comment: Here's [an example from SO using freshness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479095/django-calling-rest-api-from-models-or-views), and [a more applicable ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=data%20freshness,data%20currency&year_start=1998&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,data%20freshness;,c0;.t1;,data%20currency;,c0)

Comment: @relaxing Wow! That will remind me that with computers, there about three years to a generation instead of 30!

Answer (score 2):

To further reinforce the sentiment that using the term "**fresh**" may be the most appropriate:

Cool is often used in data contexts to refer to its availability. Hot refers to data that can be retrieved very quickly, cool data will take a bit longer and cold data will take even longer.

In one context it would be hot data in RAM, cool data on local hard drive and cold data on a network share. In another it would be hot data in Amazon DynamoDB, cool data in amazon s3 and cold data in amazon Glacier.

Answer (score 1):

In a technical context such as OP's, the adjective of choice is probably...

> [***topical***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/topical) *- of immediate relevance, interest, or importance owing to its relation to current events*.
>   [***topicality***](http://www.memidex.com/topicalities) *- the attribute of being of interest at the present time.*

Since it's a relatively specialised usage that might not be familiar to OP's co-workers, he might like to consider more transparent terms such as *[very] latest, [bang] up-to-date*.

Personally I would *not* endorse even ***fresh***, because "fresh data" often just means *data which is not currently in the system* (but it might still be "old, historical" data). Definitely don't use ***cool***.